# How do you make a value from one dictionary the key for a new dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

So say I have a dictionary

`dict{int: tuple(int, str)}`

and I want to make a new dictionary in the format

`dict{str: dict{int: int}}`

so here's an example of what I'm trying to get:

```
d1 = {
    1: (22, 'this is a phrase'),
    2: (333, 'here is a sentence')
}
```

and through a function I need to be able to manipulate that first dictionary to get me this second one:

```
d2 = {
    'this is a phrase': {1: 22},
    'here is a sentence': {2: 333},

     }
```

Really sorry for bad formatting initially and the crazy description of what I was trying to get. I just need a simple description on how to get the values to become the keys of the second dictionary. I hope this is somewhat more clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d2 = {}
# we loop through all key: value pairs in the dict
for k, v in d1.items():
    # we unpack the tuple here
    num, newkey = v
    # we then create a new entry for the newkey if it does not exist
    if newkey not in d2:
        d2[newkey] = {}
    d2[newkey][k] = num
```

and this yields

```
{'this is a phrase': {1: 22}, 'here is a sentence': {2: 333}}
```

Edited to fit the changed requirements in the question.

Comment: This actually produces an error for me! ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3). Not exactly sure why.

Comment: Your original question had 3 values in the tuple, which is why I unpacked it using 3 variables. Now, with the edited question, we should use just 2

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the order of your data is consistent like in your question, you can do the following:

```
d1 = {
    1: (22, 'this is a phrase',['apple', 'grape']),
    2: (333, 'here is a sentence',['grape', 'cherry'])
}

d2 = {}

for key, values in d1.items():
    for food in values[-1]:
        if food not in d2:
            d2[food] = {}
        d2[food][values[0]] = [values[1]]

print d2

# Output: {'cherry': {333: ['here is a sentence']}, 'grape': {333: ['here is a sentence'], 22: ['this is a phrase']}, 'apple': {22: ['this is a phrase']}}
```

Comment: How would I make it so that the keys of the second dictionary are in the same order as they appear in the first dictionary?

Comment: The issue is dictionaries are an orderless type, so you can't. What you could do is use `OrderedDict` to maintain it or use a `list` instead as the final output if order is that important.

Comment: I updated my answer to support multiple keys in the nested `dict`, so `'grape'` can now have multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the keys in `d1` to get the values to be disassembled. For each value, iterate over the items in the array `value[2]`, and insert `{value[0], value[1]}` in `d2` under each item. Assigning `d1[k1]` to a temporary variable may make it easier to read:

```
d2 = {}
for k1 in d1.keys():
    item = d1[k1]
    for k2 in item[2]:
        if k2 in d2:
          d2[k2].append({item[0]: item[1]})
        else:
          d2[k2] = [{item[0]: item[1]}]
```

Note that we check if the key is there in `d2` before trying to append; otherwise Python attempts to fetch `d2[k2]` and throws a 
`KeyError` when `k2` is not there.

Comment: Careful, the first example is producing a `TypeError` and the second example isn't resulting in the expected output stated by OP.

Comment: What if say the first key in d1 contained 'grape' within the last value's list as well? How would one ensure that the new 'grape' key of d2 contained the other values that are otherwise missing?

Comment: Thanks, @GreenCell - the corrected version should now give OP a consistent answer. I've changed the entries to lists as the `grape` entry in the original example isn't actually possible; it has to be a list, so making them all lists simplifies the code.

Comment: Is there no other way other than to make the entries lists? could you not assign a dictionary to d2?

Comment: Sure, but you'd have to decide what keys to use to store the items.